# Unexpected UI behavior when reputation goes below vote ability

Tags: support, reputation, voting, user-experience

When reputation drops below the threshold to allow for voting (such as after issuing a bounty), any voted-on answers to a question still show as being upvoted, though the score does appear to change after your ability to vote has been stripped (pretty neat actually.)

[image: Screenshot of an answer whose arrow indicates a vote]

The above image shows an answer that was voted on before a reputation change. Then, a bounty was issued which lowered reputation, which appears to have brought the score to 0 (or, perhaps someone else downvoted this person, I don't know). Either way, clicking the down arrow gives the error "Thanks for voting! Votes with less than 125 reputation...," while clicking the up arrow gives the error "You have already voted on this issue on 10/17...."

I'm not sure if this behavior is intended or what is expected, but it does seem a bit odd to me.

[Here is the Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838855/crashing-freezing-hanging-on-remove-stuck-pageflip) I noticed this in.

Comment: You *can* ask questions about these kinds of things on any meta (I believe the behavior is consistent), but I have to ask why you posted this on meta.stackoverflow.com instead of meta.askubuntu.com, which is where your behavior happened?

Comment: Cheers, that clarifies that then. The question is moot, then, because if your votes are "locked in" then it is irrelevant what your current voting abilities are, and in my mind this includes the error messages. Do you want to add your comment as an answer so I can accept and close, or do you believe this should remain open for further discussion?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I didn't know that stack existed, and I assumed behavior and styling outside of very surface-level styling was consistent across all stack boards.

Comment: @komali_2 All of the sites on the Stack Exchange network have a "meta." Q&A site associated with them (except meta.stackexchange.com). Like I said, you're free to ask here since, as you say, the sites share a lot of code. I just wanted to see if you were aware that you can ask at the meta site associated with your favorite stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moderation actions (including voting) that were valid at the time they were made are never automatically reverted after reputation loss. So any votes you cast will remain in effect with all the normal UI rules (including, as I've just verified on another site, the ability to undo votes after an edit to the post), but you won't be able to cast new votes.

So, to be more specific, you get an error message that you're unable to undo your vote because in other circumstances, even without enough reputation to cast a new vote, you *would* be able to undo it.